# Symfony - Manage javaScript and CSS with Encore package

Tags: symfony

I'm starting a new web project with `Symfony 6.3`. To manage JavaScript and CSS, do I have to install the Encore package? I think so but I'm not sure.
Is it up to me to manually create the assets/ directory with its contents or does symfonyCLI create them automatically when I install the Encore package? It's not clear to me.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: free tutorial to get you going: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore

Comment: Thanks for this tutorial link. it will be very useful for me to have a global vision of Encore.